# Why does a piecewise constant function not have a primitive function?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, riemann-integration

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases} -1, \quad & a \leq x \leq 0 \\ 1, \quad &  0 \leq x \leq b \end{cases}$$

It says in my book because of the Darboux theorem:

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable on segment $[a,b]$, then $\forall a_1, b_1 \in [a,b]: a_1<b_1\ \ \ \forall t \in [f'(a_1),f'(b_1)] \ : \exists c \in [a_1,b_1]: f'(c)=t$

I don't directly see this...

Comment: Darboux' theorem says a derivative has the intermediate value property. Your $f$ doesn't have the intermediate value property, hence it's not a derivative.

Comment: My question is why does it not have the intermediate value property?

Comment: Is there any $x$ with $f(x) = 0$, or $f(x) = 1/2$? (But note that you have conflicting definitions of $f(0)$, one of the inequalities needs to be strict.)

Comment: This is what i think: $f'(a_1)=0$ because $f(a_1)=1 \or -1 $ also applies for $b_1$ so only $0 \in [f'(a_1),f'(b_1)] $ and $f'(0)=0$ what am i misinterpreting?

Comment: You are looking in the wrong direction, $f$ would be the derivative, $f = F'$, if it had a primitive. The $f$ in the statement of Darboux' theorem plays a different role than the $f$ here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot have both $f(0)=+1$ and $f(0)=-1$, but that's hardly relevant.

And Darboux's theorem is an overkill. Just note that:

Any primitive $F$ would have to satisfy $F(x)=-x+c$ on $[a, 0)$ and $F(x)=x+d$ on $(0, b]$. Since it is differentiable (and hence continuous) at $x=0$, we need $c=d$, so in fact $F(x)=\left|x\right|+c$ and that's not differentiable at $x=0$ irrespective of the choice of $f(0)$.